# iPad App Keeps Running as an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, ios4

I recently upgraded XCode to run iOS 4.2 from iOS 3.2. However, now, when I try to run my iPad app, it appears as an iPhone app in the simulator! It appears as the smaller box with the option to expand 2x. Does anyone know why this would be so?

In addition, although the application builds and runs (albeit incorrectly), XCode still says that the Base SDK is missing. I have gone into the Build Info for the target and the project and set the following:

```
Base SDK: Latest iOS (currently set to iOS 4.2)
Targeted Device Family: iPad
iOS Deployment Target: iOS 3.2
```

**Edit** Thanks a lot for the comments; now there is no longer a Base SDK missing, but unfortunately, the app still runs as an iPhone app...

When I load a UISplitViewController, I get an exception 'UISplitViewController is only supported when running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad'.

This all seems very strange to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to set the SAME info not only for the target, but for the app itself.

Comment: Thanks, I went to the Project Build settings and set the deployment target to iOS 3.2 and device family to iPad. Still same results...

Comment: For the right configuration?  There are several different places for build settings - target, project, configuration, command-line, and environment variable.  Setting the targeted device family for release configuration when you are using the debug configuration isn't going to help.

Comment: Thanks Jim, it turns out that I was indeed editing the incorrect configuration. Now, there is a Base SDK, but the app still launches as an iPhone app...

Comment: There is a field in the project settings to set iPhone/iPad or iPhone only. You tried setting that project to iPhone/iPad and then setting iPad simulator to run your app?

Comment: Yes, this is the Targeted Device Family setting. I have set it as iPad for both the project and target settings.

Comment: Rest i can think of is clean build and check your xib files are iPad size. If all still does not work but correctly done, better off creating a new project and port everything over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually was able to fix this problem. I attempted all the methods outlined by the other answerers, but none of them worked. However, when I upgraded to XCode 4, the problem fixed itself.

I honestly don't know what changes to my app were made by this upgrade, and I am still baffled at why the project was not compiling before. I suppose upgrading your environment is one (somewhat unsatisfying) way to fix this sort of bug....

Answer (score 3):

The installed app could be broken.
What happens when you delete the app from the Simulator and do a clean build and run?

The Simulator could be broken.
What happens when you create a new different iPad app from an Xcode template?

You configuration could be broken, or you could have different settings for different targets and builds than you want, or the wrong plist or plist keys, or the wrong xib.  If the new template app works, compare these one by one.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your response. When I delete and reinstall, the same thing happen. When I create a different iPad app, it launches fine. I will compare those two and see what happens...

Comment: Clean (shift-command-K) then build worked for me. Something was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have set the appropriate settings for the current build target as well as the base project. So from the project menu:

- *Edit Project Settings*
- *Edit Active Target blah*

I have often forgotten to check the settings for the current target and had a similar experience.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I have actually set both the project settings and the active target to the same as in the original question. Unfortunately, the problem still exists.